# How to Send XML format in a string as PropertyInfo?

Tags: android, xml, android-asynctask, android-ksoap2

I'm working with KSOAP2 library and in my application i have to send an xml file in string as PropertyInfo.
The problem is that after creating the xml file and send it as String the application crashes.

Here is my code:

```
public class AsyncCommande extends AsyncTask<String, String,String>{
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                }
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_SEND);

                     PropertyInfo pi =new PropertyInfo();
                     pi.setName("xDoc");
                     pi.setValue(convertPanierToString(panier_client));

                     pi.setType(String.class);
                     request.addProperty(pi);

                     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                     envelope.dotNet = true;
                     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                     HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(getURL());
                     androidHttpTransport.debug = true ;
                     try{
                         Log.i("-------",androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
                         androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_SEND, envelope);
                         final SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                          Log.i("Reponse",response.getProperty(0).toString());

                     }
                   });
                 }
                    catch(Exception e){
                     e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    return null;
                }   
        }
```

This is the xml file but it's considered as String:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <Produits>
             <Produit>
                      <Nom>BOISSON ENERGISANTE</Nom>
                      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
             </Produit>
       </Produits>
```

And this is the output of logcut:

```
08-18 14:16:41.354: W/System.err(1892): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
08-18 14:16:41.362: W/System.err(1892):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
08-18 14:16:41.370: W/System.err(1892):     at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:160)
08-18 14:16:41.378: W/System.err(1892):     at guest.hotix.myhotix.CommanderService$AsyncCommande.doInBackground(CommanderService.java:300)
08-18 14:16:41.382: W/System.err(1892):     at guest.hotix.myhotix.CommanderService$AsyncCommande.doInBackground(CommanderService.java:1)
08-18 14:16:41.394: W/System.err(1892):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-18 14:16:41.394: W/System.err(1892):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-18 14:16:41.398: W/System.err(1892):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-18 14:16:41.402: W/System.err(1892):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-18 14:16:41.418: W/System.err(1892):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-18 14:16:41.422: W/System.err(1892):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using shared preferences like

```
SharedPreferences sp;
SharedPreferences.Editor speditor;
Button log,reg;
EditText name,pwd;    
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    sp=getSharedPreferences("userdata",MODE_PRIVATE);
    speditor=sp.edit();
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          String n,p;
            n=sp.getString("NAME","");
            p=sp.getString("PASWRD","");

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Welcome          "+name.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}});
     reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        speditor.putString("NAME",name.getText().toString());
                speditor.putString("PASWRD",pwd.getText().toString());
                speditor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Hello "+name.getText().toString()+" You are Registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    });

}
```

Comment: thnx , but you didn'i inderstand my question well :)